# Auth::check() returns false when the data id is bigger than 2147483647

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Please help, master ...

why after login is `Auth::check()` returns false when the data id is bigger than 2147483647 ?

Comment: How did you end up with `2147483647` in mysql?

Comment: The columns schema should be bigint and unsigned for `id`fields.

Answer (score 0):

The largest value of an `int` is `2147483647` as it is stated in the
(i assume you use `mysql`) [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

You may change the type of your identifier from `int` to `bigint` which supports until `2^63 - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Its the largest value of int .
make it `unsigned` in database you will have `4294967295` as maximum value.